# Zoho - Get json value from returned data

Tags: php, json

I'm using zoho crm.. 
I get the json data below returned from a query
however I'm struggling to get the value of a string inside the returned data

Here is a sample of the data returned

```
 "response": {
        "result": {
            "Deals": {
                "row": {
                    "no": "1",
                    "FL": [
                        {
                            "val": "DEALID",
                            "content": "3508588000000206039"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "SMOWNERID",
                            "content": "3508588000000176021"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Amount",
                            "content": "5000"
                        }
```

I'm trying to get the Amount value
Here is the PHP code

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
$amount = $obj->result->Deals->row->FL['Amount'];
echo 'Deal Amount : £'.$amount;
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Yeah noticed that
Juts tried  $amount = $obj->response->result->Deals->row->FL['Amount'];
echo 'Deal Amount : £'.$amount;
still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a bit

```
$amount = $obj->response->result->Deals->row->FL[2]->content;
//--------------^index------------------------^index---^column name need to be correct---
```

Comment: thanks lol works fine.. forgot about the content bit and using the key value

Comment: @ChrisYates  glad to help you :):)

Comment: any reason why when i change the module name i get a "trying to get property of non object" error ? The result is the same '{ "response": { "result": { "Leads": { "row": [ { "no": "1", "FL": [ { "val": "LEADID", "content": "3508588000000214001" }' Ive changed Deals to Leads

Comment: because `index` is cheanged. it's 0 now.it need to be:- `echo $amount = $obj->response->result->Leads->row[0]->FL[0]->content;`(https://eval.in/1057101)

Comment: ah ..
Thanks .. didnt think about the row.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with Zoho response could get messy. You could use this [library](https://cristianpontes.github.io/zoho-crm-client-php/) to help smoothen things for you.

In the meantime, `$obj->response->result->Deals->row->FL[2]->content;` should do the trick for you.